# Can't edit my address

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I want to edit my address on Careers 2.0, but when I click on save and go back to my profile, nothing have changed.

Does this happen to other people as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a bug, and should be resolved. Please reload your profile and try it again?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are right and are not alone. Currently, I am unable to edit hardly *anything* on Careers 2.0. Certainly not my email address.

Clicking on the `edit` link (the one than says "Edit your name, email, location and web site." as the tooltip next to the Gravatar image), has no effect, nothing happens. Forcing a cache reload didn't alleviate the problem. I tried this in Firefox 13, Chrome 20 and Safari 5.1.7, all on Mac OS X.

Many other `edit` links don't work either. Individual positions and education entries can be edited, but I cannot add new entries. I can edit the Stack Exchange account list, but not my background.

It looks like there is a general hickup on the Stack Exchange hosting environment today, as there was a different report about the Stack Exchange logo not showing for some: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138789/no-stackexchange-dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

To edit your email address you should go to your profile and then click on `my logins`. There you can add another login, it being the email you want to use.

Comment: it's my geographical address i try to modify :-)