# Most edit links not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't edit my address](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138790/cant-edit-my-address)

After clicking `my profile` on **careers.stackoverflow.com**, almost every edit button does nothing upon clicking. 
I have tried in both Chrome and Firefox. `Right clicking` and selecting `open link in a new tab` works fine.

Also, the "I am a student" checkbox does not toggle.

Comment: Dupe of [Can't edit my address](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138790) I think.