# How do I edit my profile on Careers?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, profile-page

I know that may be strange but I can't seem to find a way to edit my Careers profile. Some sections are missing I guess, when I click on "Add a personal statement" or "Add some technologies you like" from the right menu panel nothing happens, it's like some anchors do not exist and in fact in my profile page there is only the header with basic information, the stack exchange bar, the app &software bar and last writing and reading bars. I'd really like to improve my profile but I don't know how. I don't know if it can help but I received my invite yesterday.

Comment: Same with my profile page here... I think this may be a bug.

Comment: Mine still works, but it is not unheard of (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138790/cant-edit-my-address/).

Comment: Address edit works fine, too bad it's the only edit that works :D

Comment: Same with my profile. I can edit all sections where i already have content. However the education section is missing for example.

Comment: If you import a Linkeding profile education and employment will unlock, however if you remove them they will disappear again.

Comment: Yes, some sections are being hidden when they shouldn’t. Stand by for a fix.

Comment: Nice job guys, now it works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try a force reload; JavaScript may have failed to load.

Generally, though, you can edit your profile right from the http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv page. There are `edit` links all over the place:

[image]

Comment: I tried CTRL+F5 and I even deleted my cache. Tried with IE (I use Chrome) but same error. It seems strange...

Comment: I have same problem, not able to edit CV

Comment: @BhaveshHirpara: the UI for Developer Stories has changed dramatically, and 'not able to edit CV' doesn't tell me anything about what you are doing and how that differs from what *should* work. I can edit my own Developer Story directly on the [story view page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current); each section has an edit link; the top half when moving the mouse over it, and in the timeline section, each entry has a gear icon with a menu.